# Position Text with variable in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I'd like to place some text in my scatterplot, which I made with `ggplot` like you can see in the top left corner of the plot:

The text is now showing "Text" and "Variable", but should show more "Text" after the "Variable" and should be left aligned:

[image]

The requirements are:

- It must have the format "Text" "Variable" "Text"
- I need two or three rows
- The rows should be left-aligned

What I did is using this code, but it might be not adequate for my intentions:

```
  p1 + annotate(geom="text", x=1, y = 15, col="black",
           label=paste("atop(' Mean diff = '*",bias,",'SD of diff = '*",sd,")"), parse=T)
```

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Read about [ggtext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtext/vignettes/plotting_text.html).